# Changing image size in README.Md file on Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, markdown

I have added an image in README.md file something like this

```
![Logo](./images/Logo-doc.png)
```

The image displayed on Bitbucket is too large and I want to be able to resize the image. Following is what I have tried which didn't work

```
![Logo](./images/Logo-doc.png){:width="320px"}
![Logo](./images/Logo-doc.png =320x)
![Logo](./images/Logo-doc.png){width=320}!
![Logo](./images/Logo-doc.png){width=320px}
```

Can someone please help me with a solution to resize the image in README.md file?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can always use HTML in a MarkDown document.
The equivalent code would be:

```html
<img src="./images/Objy-InfiniteGraph-doc.png" alt="InfiniteGraph Logo" width="320">
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything for me in bitbucket.  Works great in github, no chagne in bitbucket

Comment: Doesn't work in bitbucket but works great on github as @SethLutske said.